# Set all checkboxes to true after DOM page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes that are created using for loops with Javascript only once the web page has loaded.

I want to make all the checkboxes set to true by default, I can do this in the console, but when I put it in my script, it doesn't work since the function probably loads before the DOM elements have loaded.

I've tried two different approaches, and neither seem to work. In both cases, they only work for the hardcoded checkboxes I typed up (not generated by for loops/DOM). If anyone knows how I can resolve this, I'd be very grateful!

Here is my basic jQuery/JS code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var setTrue = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < setTrue.length; i++) {
    setTrue[i].checked = true;
  };
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
  var setTrue = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < setTrue.length; i++) {
    setTrue[i].checked = true;
  };
});
```

Comment: You can't set something as checked if it doesn't exist yet.  You can only do it once it exists.  So, change them after they are created.  Pretty straight forward issue.

Comment: Is this in an extension or is it a page you control the code for?

Comment: It's a page I control, that I'm creating. Usually, when you go to a page, the checkboxes are set to true by default since their are many of them. I'm trying to figure out how to set them to true after the checkboxes are created.

Comment: Add the logic that sets them to checked, **after** the logic that creates them.  OR change the logic that creates them to make them checked in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Taplar, that's a good solution, I'll just set them to true by default when creating them in a for loop. Doh!

Comment: I mean, yeah.  Rather than fixing the problem, don't create the problem in the first place, :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example which sets the attribute of all checkboxes on the current page to checked.

```
$(function(){
   $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true)
})
```

Comment: You should not use `attr` to set Boolean properties like `checked`. Use `prop` instead. See the documentation for [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Also, answers consisting of code without explanation tend to get downvoted more often than those which explain why the code is better than the OP.

Comment: Perhaps, but if you read the documentation, you'll see that they advise the use of `prop`, in bold no less.

Comment: @HereticMonkey will take it into consideration

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got the right way to do it from the comments, which is to change the javascript that adds the checkboxes to just add them with a checked property initially.  But for others that are looking to do something similar, where they don't have control over the checkboxes, your jQuery function works, but can be done much more simply like this:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true)
}
```

jQuery will already do the looping through the input objects for you (and in your attempt, you would end up adding 'checked' to every input, not just checkboxes).

Comment: You should not use `attr` to set Boolean properties like `checked`. Use `prop` instead. See the documentation for [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).